# Many ToMany field data not able to render

Tags: python, django

I got an issue while accessing the Django modal data so here t-is my modal .

```
class People(models.Modal):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=something, db_index=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=something, db_index=True)


class MyService(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=something, db_index=True)
    peoples = models.ManyToManyField(People, null=True, blank=True)
```

Here is some view part

```
services  = MyService.objects.all()
context['services'] = services
```

I am trying to access the many to many field data in my templates like

```
{% for service in services.peoples_set.all %}
        {{service.name}}
    {% endfor %}
```

I am not able to access those details .

Please help me out what might I am doing wrong here .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`services` is `QuerySet`, not a model instance.

If you want to display names of services, iterate `services`:

```
{% for service in services %}
    {{service.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to display name of people, you need nested `for`:

```
{% for service in services %}
    {% for person in service.peoples.all %}
        {{ person.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: object has no attribute people_set

Comment: 'instancemethod' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes here.

Firstly, as falsetru points out, `services` is a QuerySet. That is, it is a container of all services - and *each one* has its own set of People.

Secondly, you have defined the many-to-many field directly on Service, so you use the field name you have actually defined there - `people` - not the reverse relationship.

So:

```
{% for service in services %}
    {{ service.name }}
    {% for people in service.peoples.all %}
        {{ people.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```